# Virgin birth in other religions and relevance to Christianity

Tags: life-of-jesus, virgin-mary, incarnation

Like [flood legends](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3544/are-other-flood-legends-relevant-to-christians), legends of heroes of virgin birth and/or virginal conception are not uncommon in faiths across the world.  For example, the [Bhagavata Purana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishna#Birth) tells that Krishna was conceived without sex.  There are [many others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miraculous_births).

When I was coming up in sunday school and reading Christian literature as a young adult, I remember that the virginal conception was taught to be a pretty special thing about Jesus.  I don't believe I *ever* heard that this concept was found in other faiths.  It was as if the very uniqueness and absurdity of this claim was enough to show it was true and proved Jesus was divine.

With the flood stories or other ideas which are found in other faiths, the other faiths' stories are often seen as corroborating the biblical account.  This could make sense because those stories could be seen as coming after the biblical event or concept.  *But* since most of the stories of sexless conception pre-date Christ (though of course [not all](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chosen_One)), they are somewhat different.

Is there anything a Christian might take away from the fact virgin births are found in other beliefs?  Perhaps some kind of global prophecy?  Or is it no more relevant than the fact [faith healing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamanism) and [resurrection](http://www.pantheon.org/articles/a/asclepius.html) are also found in other faiths?

(also, didn't find very good tags for this, help if you can)

Comment: I notice an edit changing my "immaculate conception" in the second paragraph to "incarnation".  But I specifically mean to refer to the fact Jesus became incarnated by growing in a human womb but without involving human sex-- not the general fact he was incarnated.  As "incarnation" more generally refers to divine  inhabiting human flesh, that is too general because it excludes the mechanism.

Comment: @Peter - what is a better way to phrase this and specifically refer to the mechanism of incarnation?  Maybe my terminology is wrong but incarnation is too general, of that much I am sure.

Comment: Immaculate Conception refers to Mary's conception, if this is a term borrowed and misapplied in Protestant theology then I'm sorry for the indignation.

Comment: How about [tag:virgin-birth].   BTW captial "I" "Incarnation" ought to be understood to refer to Jesus being incarnate of the Holy Spirit in the womb of the Virgin Mary. http://newadvent.org/cathen/07706b.htm

Comment: @PeterTurner - ok, I think the terminology confusion is mine, sorry.  it's been a long time since I spoke of this stuff... but that's why I'm on this site, to learn.  thanks

Comment: This question isn't really related to Christiainity.  There are no Christian doctrines (that I know of) that state that Christians should look towards other beliefs for their source of inspiration or knowledge.  As such, this is more of a philosophy question or sociology question than a question regarding Christian doctrines, traditions, and living.  Therefore, I'm closing this as Off Topic for this site.  [You may also find this post interesting, as it clarifies the quality standards for questions.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/690/84)

Comment: @richard regarding Catholic views towards other religions: http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_decl_19651028_nostra-aetate_en.html I agree in principle that we don't look to other religions, but you only attempt to deny that there were ancient religions that have anything to do with Christianity, it's very hard to deny it altogether.

Comment: @PeterTurner That is a great link and a great read!  It seems to be summarized that we should live in peace with all religions and all men, seeking peace and understanding.  I think that's a very solid doctrine.  *However*, living in peace with them and drawing understanding of our own religion from their teachings are very different.  I believe the latter is the source of this question.  As such, it seems to be quite off-topic for this site.  (Still, very nice link!)

Comment: @Richard - if the answer is "there is no relevance" that must still be on topic.  I specifically phrased the question from the POV of what a Christian might make of this.  How is this more off topic than the Flood question for instance?  And I specifically phrased it not as "what can Christians learn from those faiths" but instead "what can Christians learn from the fact those faiths believe similar things" which is a pretty different concept... I dispute this close as off topic.

Comment: The answer of "there is no relevance" raises the question of **["According to which doctrine?"](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/690/84)**  If the answer is "it is relevant", it raises the question ["According to which doctrine?"](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/690/84) If there is no relevance to Christianity (regardless of doctrine), it doesn't belong on this site.  ("What is the relevance of Dr. Seuss stories to Christianity?" is a useless question.)     [The flood question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3544/84) has also been closed for the same reason.

Comment: @Richard - ok, I get your position here.  However, this attitude is a huge part of why I had to walk away from Christian faith -- Christian truth as a completely closed system...  If it's not in the Bible or codified in some church's official doctrine, then it's not a relavent piece of information to a Christian worldview... sorry, but to me that just seems so backwards.

Comment: @zipquincy In my belief, this is not the case in the least.  However, the StackExchange format is a Question-Answer format.  That means we need to stick to a specific structure when it comes to questions.  Questions that are open-ended lead to debate and speculation.  These questions are not constructive for the format of this site.  This is a StackExchange standard, not a Christianity.SE standard and definitely not a "Christianity" standard.  The problems that this question has is not a "Christian" problem, but a "StackExchange" problem.

Comment: @Richard - actually, based on my participation in other SE sites, I have to agree with you.  i understand why they designed it that way, but it seems to cause problems... peace

Answer (score 3):

**On other "virgin births" predating the concept of a virgin birth in Christianity:**

The notion of the virgin birth in Christianity predates the actual birth of Christ too; it was prophesied explicitly some centuries earlier. Certainly in Isaiah, we have:

[Isaiah 7:14 (MSG):](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%207:14&version=MSG)

> So the Master is going to give you a sign anyway. Watch for this: A
>   girl who is presently a virgin will get pregnant. She'll bear a son
>   and name him Immanuel (God-With-Us)

In addition, the fact that this verse in Genesis (known as the Protoevangelium*) talks of "*her* offspring" when it was/is more usual to refer to the offspring of a couple as being of the father rather than the mother, is [interpreted by some theologians](http://themoorings.org/apologetics/VirginBirth/Isaiah.html) as a prophecy, or at the very least a hint, of a virgin birth:

[Genesis 3:15 (MSG)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%203:15&version=MSG):

> God told the serpent:     "Because you've done this, you're cursed, 
>         cursed beyond all cattle and wild animals,     Cursed to slink on your belly 
>         and eat dirt all your life.     I'm declaring war between you and the Woman, 
>         between your offspring and hers.     He'll wound your head, 
>         you'll wound his heel."

Because this happens right at the beginning of the human race, arguably this reference to virgin birth predates all others (although it is of course less explicit in meaning than the Isaiah prophecy).

**Relevance of other virgin birth stories to Christianity**

Because there is that hint of a virgin birth right at the beginning of things, the comparison you draw to flood legends is a good one. It is logical that any culture with a collective recollection of the Flood may also have a collective recollection of the events before it; the Creation and the Fall, in which we find the Protoevangelium. In that respect the relevance of legends of virgin births to Christianity is similar to [the relevance of flood legends to Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3544/are-other-flood-legends-relevant-to-christians).

<sub>*Not to be confused with the [Protoevangelium of James](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_James)</sub>

Comment: If, as per the question, the discussion is comparing to other religions, the "Because this happens right at the beginning of the human race" note is suspect, as is the explanation that this therefore accounts for the commonality - for the simple reason that the other religions involved **won't agree with you on those points**. Otherwise it is circular, i.e. (over-simplified for emphasis) "the Christian view is accurate... look, it says so right here in the Bible!". Comparative theology is... hard.

Comment: @MarcGravell Of course the other religions won't agree. If this is purely a comparative theology question it is off topic here; we're not a comparative theology site. The question is asking for a Christian perspective; I'm not convinced the fact that other religions disagree with it invalidates the answer. I'm not attempting to argue the case for the "Christian view" here, just to state what that view is.

Comment: Arguably, that could be used to explain all similarities.... Not sure it is a *strong* argument though.

Comment: @Waggers - I am with you but I think Marc's argument stands from a biblical perspective which _is_ what I'm asking about.  Also Waggers - I am having a hard time seeing a prophesy the virgin birth in Genesis 3:15 - what am I missing?

Comment: @zipquincy It's very tenuous. It's the fact that the offspring ("seed" in some translations) is of the woman (Eve) whereas normally offspring would be expressed as being of a man. The implication is that no man was involved in producing the offspring.

Comment: @MarcGravell Actually I'm not sure it could explain all similarities; and again, we're not here to argue or even to assess the strength of the reasoning behind other people's arguments. (I know it's difficult to resist the temptation, I've succumbed a few times already)

Comment: @Waggers (site context) true; I only commented at all because the wider religious context was central to the question

Answer (score 1):

Chesterton notes this assumption in the "[Ball and the Cross](http://www.fullbooks.com/The-Ball-and-The-Cross1.html)"

> With a smart journalistic instinct characteristic of all his
>   school, the editor of *The Atheist* had put first in his paper
>   and most prominently in his window an article called "The
>   Mesopotamian Mythology and its Effects on Syriac Folk Lore." Mr.
>   Evan MacIan began to read this quite idly, as he would have read
>   a public statement beginning with a young girl dying in Brighton
>   and ending with Bile Beans. He received the very considerable
>   amount of information accumulated by the author with that tired
>   clearness of the mind which children have on heavy summer
>   afternoons--that tired clearness which leads them to go on asking
>   questions long after they have lost interest in the subject and
>   are as bored as their nurse.
>
> The streets were full of people and
>   empty of adventures. He might as well know about the gods of
>   Mesopotamia as not; so he flattened his long, lean face against
>   the dim bleak pane of the window and read all there was to read
>   about Mesopotamian gods. He read how the Mesopotamians had a god
>   named Sho (sometimes pronounced Ji), and that he was described as
>   being very powerful, a striking similarity to some expressions
>   about Jahveh, who is also described as having power. Evan had
>   never heard of Jahveh in his life, and imagining him to be some
>   other Mesopotamian idol, read on with a dull curiosity. He learnt
>   that the name Sho, under its third form of Psa, occurs in an
>   early legend which describes how the deity, after the manner of
>   Jupiter on so many occasions, seduced a Virgin and begat a hero.
>   This hero, whose name is not essential to our existence, was, it
>   was said, the chief hero and Saviour of the Mesopotamian ethical
>   scheme. Then followed a paragraph giving other examples of such
>   heroes and Saviours being born of some profligate intercourse
>   between God and mortal.

And this is our natural reaction to such statements:

> Then followed a paragraph--but Evan did
>   not understand it. He read it again and then again. Then he did
>   understand it. The glass fell in ringing fragments on to the
>   pavement, and Evan sprang over the barrier into the shop,
>   brandishing his stick.

The Catholic doesn't think about these things unless provoked, he knows that the Virgin Mary is his mother and recognizes that other religions have other mothers and leaves it at that.

The prophecy that "A virgin (or even a young woman) shall bear a son and he will be called God with Us" (Isaiah 7:14) may be a prophecy that is not unique as a prophecy to Christianity or Judaism. But it is unique as a matter of fact, in that it came true.

Christianity is about covenants and renewal, God's part of the covenant is that He keeps His promises.  How He fulfills them is purely up to Him.  Nobody expected wisemen to come looking for Jesus following a star, except maybe the wisemen and God. Catholics also believe that whereas Christianity is the fullness of truth, other religions have hints of it and sometimes more than hints.

That these things should happen throughout history is just a foreshadowing of the goodness of God which is written on our souls when we're created.  It's unavoidable that things which are the same should bear some similarity, it doesn't mean everyone looks at them the same way or everyone is right about how they look at them.

Comment: So your "natural reaction" to having your assumptions challenged is outraged and outrageous violence, consisting of criminal damage and threats of assault?

Comment: As well it should be.

Comment: I have no words.

Comment: @Trig has anyone ever insulted your mother before? I wouldn't go out of my way to do so. It's my understanding that those who insult mothers are really begging for a fight and may actually need to learn the hard way not to do so. If it came to that, would you actually fight a man in defense of your words, which are so very insulting to the true faith?

Comment: Well, I honestly don't see where I've insulted anyone in this exchange, but since you've both insulted and slandered me before, let's call it quits, shall we?