# What are the main similarities and differences between the Genesis and other major ancient flood accounts?

Tags: genesis, flood-of-noah, extra-biblical, christian-literature

Have any of you read the Atrahasis Epic? It's the Babylonian/Akkadian version of the Great Flood. I found it had striking similarities with the Flood Account in Genesis!! (Read it if you have not already... it's also funny – or petty – because the gods wrought on the flood because the humans are loud and disrupt their sleep). Not only is there the obvious great flood, but the hero (Noah & Atrahasis) of the story and their families are told to build an ark and collect two animals of each kind. And both Atrahasis and Noah offer a sacrifice once the flood recedes.

Now I know that there are other ancient Flood Stories out there as well, i.e. Enuma Elish and the 11th Tablet of the Gilgamesh Epic. I'm compiling a list of their similarities, but do any of you know the Atrahasis, Genesis, and Gilgamesh stories well enough to know their differences? My aim is to have a venn diagram of these three flood stories to teach a class, but I'm not so familiar with Gilgamesh's Flood version. Or it seems to me that there would already be a venn diagram comparing/contrasting these three flood stories online, but I have not had such luck locating one. Can you help me out with that?

I think once I can see all their traits on one chart, I can began to see the divine (and different) purpose that the Genesis flood serves that the others do not.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing. This is a good question, but may prove somewhat broad for our site.  Perhaps, because you've specified two particular accounts (Atrahasis and Gilgamesh), a suitable answer could be given within a reasonable length. If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: You should get hold of [*Before the Flood*](https://www.amazon.com/Before-Flood-Biblical-Changed-Civilization/dp/0312319711) by Ian Wilson. He looks at the legends and the archaeology as a scientist would.

Comment: Related: [Are other flood legends relevant to Christians?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3544/6071)

Comment: Cross-posted on BH.SE: [Genesis Flood Compared/Contrasted with Atrahasis & Gilgamesh?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/23270/9713)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. I found them very helpful!